# How to get logged user name and email using “Sign In with Apple JS"?

Tags: javascript, apple-id, sign-in-with-apple

I can't seem to understand the documentation about “Sign In with Apple JS”. I have manage to make first step (the login part and the redirection) but I don't know how to get and display the logged user name and email.

Please help.

Comment: Second part is more complex. You will receive `code` field in this callback. perform request to token API with this code, decode id_token field in response with jwt library. Along the way you will have to create client_secret with jwt library.

Comment: And the bad thing is that there is no user name in this response only id and email.

Comment: what should we do as there is no user's name ?